# Similar Lines of Code, Vastly Different Performance

Tags: objective-c, ios, performance, core-graphics

I'm writing a drawing app for the iPad and was doing some time profiling so I could see where my drawing could potentially be sped up at.

In my drawing method, I have the following 4 lines of code:

```
    CGContextDrawImage([DrawingState sharedState].context, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [DrawingState sharedState].screenWidth, [DrawingState sharedState].screenHeight), unzoomedBufferImage);

    CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage([DrawingState sharedState].context);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 768, 1024), image);
    CGImageRelease(image);
```

The first line accounts for 18.8% of the time, the second, third, and fourth lines only account for 4.5% of the time, with the CGContextDrawImage line accounting for 3.5%.

Why do these two CGContextDrawImage functions have such vastly different performance (18.8% vs 3.5%)?

Note:  [DrawingState sharedState].screenWidth and [DrawingState sharedState].screenHeight are 768 and 1024, respectively, so in theory, I'm doing the same amount of drawing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using sampling, this may not be a completely accurate picture of where you're spending your time..

I'd try this code:

```
DrawingState * state = [ DrawingState sharedState ] ;
CGContextRef context = state.context ;
CGRect r = { .size = { state.screenWidth, state.screenHeight } } ;

CGContextDrawImage( context, r, unzoomedBufferImage);

CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage( context );
CGContextDrawImage(context, r, image);
CGImageRelease(image);
```

Just to get more info.

i.e. When things don't make sense, try changing your assumptions about what you "know to be true"

If this doesn't reveal any info, you could try instrumenting your code with my profiling macros: https://gist.github.com/1905396 :)

Comment: Exactly what I was going to suggest! While the _actual_ time of the `sharedState` method call is likely to be minimal, its impact on that line's _share_ of the time may be significant.

Comment: Let me give that a shot and post back.  However, for the record, [DrawingState sharedState].context and context are not the same!  They are two different contexts.

Comment: Wait, I sort of just answered my question with that last comment!  In "context", I am only drawing to part of the screen (based on the rectangle passed by drawRect).  In [DrawingState sharedState].context, I am drawing to a context that is the full size of the screen every time!  Thanks for suggesting I separate them like that, it made it much easier to see that they are different contexts and refer to different sizes.

Comment: That would make a difference!